# SQL Query with CASE and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Feature Table where each feature is identified by its ID(DB column) and Bugs table where each feature has one to many relation ship with bugs table.

```
Feature Table has columns
id Description

Bugs Table has columns

ID Feature_ID Status
```

I will consider a bug as opened if its state is either 0 or 1 and as closed if Status is 2.

I am trying write a query which indicates whether a Feature can be considered as passed or failed based on it's Status.

```
 select F.ID
        CASE WHEN count(B.ID) > 0 THEN 'FAIL'
             ELSE 'PASS' 
         END as FEATURE_STATUS 
 from Feature F,
      Bugs B 
where B.Status in (0,1) 
group by F.ID;
```

My query always gives the Failed Features but not passed, how can modify my query to return both?

Comment: This makes no sense at all B.ID is always greater then > 0 so ALL tuples will be failed.

Comment: What makes a record become in a fail state or pass state - you don't mention this.

Comment: @JonH i have already mentioned that my query is wrong and alwyas returns failed status. It is marked passed or failed by external client

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like

```
SELECT f.id,
       (CASE WHEN open_bugs = 0 
             THEN 'PASS'
             ELSE 'FAIL'
         END) feature_status,
       open_bugs,
       closed_bugs
  FROM (SELECT f.id,
               SUM( CASE WHEN b.status IN (0,1)
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                     END) open_bugs,
               SUM( CASE WHEN b.status = 2
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                     END) closed_bugs
          FROM feature f
               JOIN bugs b ON (f.id = b.feature_id)
         GROUP BY f.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT F.ID, 
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN B.ID IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Fail'
            ELSE 'Success' END AS FEATURE_STATUS 
 from Feature F
      JOIN Bugs B ON B.Feature_ID = F.ID    
group by F.ID
```